# Population growth model not corresponding to expectations

Tags: c++, c, modeling

I'm trying to make a bacteria model just for fun, and i'm using the pow(a, b) function as a function to calculate the growth of the population. When the bacteria population hits the maximum amount of food units that it's environment can provide, it declines by 70%, as a result of competition between the individuals. I'm saving the results to a txt so I can plot it later. The problem I'm having is that the population oscillates correctly until I reach a number of reproduction cycles arount t = 900, then the population just defaults to 0.
The code follows bellow, I hope you don't mind the name of variables and functions written Portuguese.

```
bool
check_aliemento (unsigned long int *pop)
{
    if (*pop >= MAX_ALIMENTO) return false;
    return true;
}

unsigned long int
replicaBacteria (unsigned long int *popInit, unsigned int tempo_t, double taxa)
{
    unsigned long int nextPop = round ((*popInit) * 
                static_cast<double> (pow (1 + taxa, tempo_t))); 
                //I'm almost sure that the problem happens in this pow() function
    while (! check_aliemento (&nextPop))
    {
        nextPop = (0.7 * nextPop);
    }
    return nextPop;
}



   int
main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    unsigned long int a = 2;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ( "C:\\Users\\Pedro\\Desktop\\values.txt" );
    for ( unsigned int i; i < 1000; i ++ )
    {
        unsigned long int pop = replicaBacteria ( &a, i, 0.05 );
        myfile << pop << " ==> time = " << i;
        myfile << "\r\n";
    }
    myfile.close ( );
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
8080 ==> time = 872
8484 ==> time = 873
8909 ==> time = 874
9354 ==> time = 875
9822 ==> time = 876
7219 ==> time = 877
7580 ==> time = 878
7958 ==> time = 879
8357 ==> time = 880
8775 ==> time = 881
9214 ==> time = 882
9675 ==> time = 883
7110 ==> time = 884
7466 ==> time = 885
7839 ==> time = 886
8232 ==> time = 887
8643 ==> time = 888
9075 ==> time = 889
9529 ==> time = 890
7003 ==> time = 891
7354 ==> time = 892
7721 ==> time = 893
8108 ==> time = 894
8513 ==> time = 895
0 ==> time = 896
0 ==> time = 897
0 ==> time = 898
0 ==> time = 899
0 ==> time = 900
```

Comment: Change your `data type int to long long` may be due to Population is increased too much so it can't be stored in int .

Comment: I've made sure that in this case, the population dosen't goes over 10000, which perfectly fits an int.

Comment: What is the initial value of i ?

Comment: The compiler automatically sets it to 0. The beauty of gcc!

Comment: Yes it's problem in your nextPop check it value by printing it .

Comment: @john you were write after all. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pow (1 + taxa, tempo_t)
```

Obviously `long int` can't hold `2^900` so what you are seeing here is integer overflow use a data-type which can hold large values like

`unsigned long long`

Comment: The problem is in the method used, more fundamentally than in the size of the variable.  The population is meant to decline as soon as it exceeds 10,000, but the way it is at present, it grows to enormous size and then is bumped down repeatedly by factors of 0.7 until it falls below 10,000.  This is, I do not think, what is wanted.

Comment: @Tony if its not much of a hassle, would you mind providing a better method?

Answer (score 2):

You are overflowing the `long int` `nextPop`.  This is because you are calculating population growth as if it were uninterrupted for 896 generations, and only after that reducing the population until it falls below your magic limit (10,000 here, you say).

A way to solve this is to retain the population after each iteration and grow that by 5%, then cutting the result to 70% if necessary.

So instead of `unsigned long int pop = replicaBacteria ( &a, i, 0.05 );`, you want something like `pop = replicaBacteria ( pop, 0.05 );` (declare the variable before the loop), and then `replicaBacteria` should simply multiply its input by 5% and scale to 70% of the result if necessary.

**Following code edited to produce something that compiles and runs for me**

Like this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_ALIMENTO 10000

double
replicaBacteria (double popInit, double taxa)
{
    double nextPop = popInit * (1 + taxa); 
    while (nextPop >= MAX_ALIMENTO)
    {
        nextPop = (0.7 * nextPop);
    }
    return nextPop;
}



   int
main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::ofstream myfile( "/tmp/out.txt" );
    double pop = 2;
    unsigned int i;
    for ( i=0; i < 1000; i ++ )
    {
        pop = replicaBacteria ( pop, 0.05 );
        myfile << round(pop) << " ==> time = " << i;
        myfile << "\r\n";
    }
    myfile.close ( );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 ==> time = 0
2 ==> time = 1
2 ==> time = 2
2 ==> time = 3
3 ==> time = 4
3 ==> time = 5
3 ==> time = 6
3 ==> time = 7
3 ==> time = 8
3 ==> time = 9
3 ==> time = 10
4 ==> time = 11
...
8925 ==> time = 990
9371 ==> time = 991
9840 ==> time = 992
7232 ==> time = 993
7594 ==> time = 994
7974 ==> time = 995
8372 ==> time = 996
8791 ==> time = 997
9230 ==> time = 998
9692 ==> time = 999
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood. I'll try to correct it. Just a sec

Comment: in this way, because the growth is so slow, the round() function always evaluates the value of the population to 2.

Comment: Either start the population at something higher than 2 (e.g. because you can manually calculate the first, say, 50 generations) or make the variable a double instead of an int (you can have it print a rounded number, but keep storing the fractional results.)  I will edit my response to see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

even unsigned long long int  can't hold .
When tempo_t > 895 then

```
unsigned long long int nextPop = round ((*popInit) * 
                    static_cast<double> (pow (1 + taxa, tempo_t)));
```

This expression evaluate to zero  so you have to decrease life time of bacteria .

Answer (score 2):

Change your function a little bit to understand when the number becomes zero:

```
unsigned long int
replicaBacteria (unsigned long int *popInit, unsigned int tempo_t, double taxa)
{
   double r = round ((*popInit) * static_cast<double> (pow (1 + taxa, tempo_t))); 
   std::cout << r << std::endl;
   unsigned long int nextPop = r;
   std::cout << nextPop << std::endl;

   //I'm almost sure that the problem happens in this pow() function
   while (! check_aliemento (&nextPop))
   {
      nextPop = (0.7 * nextPop);
   }
   return nextPop;
}
```

I see the following output:

```
1.84269e+19
18426916303946758144
8513 ==> time = 895
1.93483e+19
0
0 ==> time = 896
2.03157e+19
0
0 ==> time = 897
```

This is on a 64-bit Linux machine using g++ 4.8.2. Since you are seeing zero starting at `896`, it's safe to assume that your compiler has the exact same problem. The largest number that can be represented by `unsigned long int` is smaller than `1.93483e+19`.